# Incrementing value of an array from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
$array1 = array(22,193,124);
$array2 = array(array('id'=>22, 'count'=> 1), array('id'=>124, 'count'=>2));
```

Now I need to search in $array2 for id from $array1 and if found to increment the count value and also add to the array the one's which are not found with a count as 1 so my resulting array would be

```
$arr = array(array('id'=>22, 'count'=> 2), array('id'=>124, 'count'=>3), array('id'=>193, 'count'=>1));
```

any help would be appreciated

The current code which I tried is

```
if($array2){
            foreach($array1 as $array){

                if(in_array($array, array_column($array2, 'id'))){                  
                    $wa_array['count'] += 1;
                } else {
                    $wa_array['id'] = $array;
                    $wa_array['count'] = 1;
                }
            }

        } else {
            foreach($array1 as $array){
                $wa_array['id'] = $array;
                $wa_array['count'] = 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's not valid PHP code.

Comment: Why? It Is valid.

Comment: You either need to remove the `array` keywords or replace `[` and `]` with `(` and `)`.

Comment: Hint: Use a `for` loop to iterate over `$array1`, Use `in_array()` to test if the id is in `$array1`, and if it is, increment the count.

Comment: @Barmar tried with for loop too but doesnt work as needed

Comment: What is `$wa_array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be something you are looking for -

```
$array1 = array(22,193,124);
$array2 = array(array('id'=>22, 'count'=> 1), array('id'=>124, 'count'=>2));

foreach($array1 as $key=>$digit)
{
  $keyFound = array_search($digit, array_column($array2, 'id'));

  if($keyFound === false)
    {
      array_push($array2, ['id'=>$digit, 'count'=>1]);
    }
  else
    {
      $array2[$keyFound]['count']++;
    }
}

print_r($array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so clear, so I will go with my understanding : You need to check if values inside the first array are in the second array. If yes, increment the count value of that second array, if not, create that element with the value of 1.

This code is not tested, hope this can help find the good solution.

```
  foreach($array1 as $value){
     searchForId($value,$array2);
  }

  function searchForId($id, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
      if ($val['id'] === $id) {
       $val['count'] += 1;
      }else{
        array_push(array('id'=>$id,'count'=>1))
      }
    }
  return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should loop through `$array2`, not `$array1`. Finding the value in `array_column($array2, 'id')` doesn't tell you the index of the array element to increment.

```
foreach ($array2 as &$item) {
    if (in_array($item['id'], $array1)) {
        $item['count']++;
    }
}
```

Note that you have to use `&$item` to make this a reference to the original array element, so that modifying it will update `$array2`. Otherwise, `$item` would be a copy of the array element.

If `$array1` is large, it would be better to convert it to an associative array so you can test membership more efficiently.

```
$array1_assoc = array_flip($array1);
```

Then the test in the loop becomes:

```
if (isset($array1_assoc[$item['id']]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. NOTE: But this has O(n^2) complexity.

```
$array1 = [22,193,124];

$array2 = [['id'=>22, 'count'=> 1], ['id'=>124, 'count'=>2]];

foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    $isFound = false;
    foreach ($array2 as &$item) {
        if ($value == $item['id']) {
           $item['count']++;
           $isFound = true;
           continue;
        }
    }
    if ($isFound == false) {
       $array2 [] = ['id'=>$value, 'count'=> 1];
    }
}

var_dump($array2);
```